# JS variables across domains

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, https, cross-domain

**Problem**

I want to receive javascript variables from another HTTPS domain but I got error.

**What I've Tried**

This is the most simplified version of my code that I've been able to get, which still produces the problem I described above.

```
 $.ajax({
          url: "https://www.example.com/page.asp",
          crossDomain:true,
          success:function(data){
                alert("success")
          },
          error : function() {
             alert("error")
          }
      });
```

and I also tried

```
$.ajax({
          url: "https://www.example.com/page.asp",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          cache: true,
          success:function(data){
                alert("success")
          },
          error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("error")
          }
      });
```

and the codes below also added in the remote page

```
<%Response.AddHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*"%>
```

It does not work because it gives the following error:

> 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access.

**Question**

So my basic question is, how do I receive javascript variables from HTTPS page to HTTP page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to receive javascript variables with the following codes:

```
$.ajax({
   method: "GET",
   url: "http://www.example.com/test.js",
   dataType: "script",
   success:function(data){
     alert(variable)
   }
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set in web.config?
I use it only with asp.net web api, and in it there is a dll for manage cors.

```
<httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <clear />
            <add name="X-Powered-By" value="ASP.NET" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept, X-Access-Token, X-Application-Name, X-Request-Sent-Time"/>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"/>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
        </customHeaders>
        <redirectHeaders>
            <clear />
        </redirectHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: but this way may lowers the security, isn't it?

Comment: if you want to improve security you can use an api system with token or simply write the domain on the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, so the permission in not for all but only for that domain.